# unable to get unpack() usage correct in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert someone else's 10 year old python2 script to python3.  I have fixed most of the issues but am stuck on this one.  There is the line

```
(a,b,c,d) = unpack('!HIIH', someData)
```

When run I get this:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Lots of article online about exactly this problem but none of them point me at the correct answer.  I have tried using the 'bytes' function in various ways on the someData object but nothing works.

Additional information is that I believe the origin of the someData object is via this piece of code in another module:

```
e = str()

for i in range((len(plaintext))):
     e += chr(ord(plaintext[i]) ^ ord(counter[i]))

return e
```

In python2 this apparently worked.  In python3 the line beginning
`e += chr(ord(...` produces the error:

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

I solved this by changing the line (based on Internet searching)  to

```
e += chr(plaintext[i] ^ counter[i])
```

someData is assigned the output of e

In python2, the statement (a,b,c,d) = unpack('!HIIH', someData) worked without issue, but as originally stated, in python3 the TypeError occurs.

Thank you.

Comment: You first need to look back to find where `someData` is being set. Perhaps a change there will *keep* it of type byte instead of wrongly converting it to a str type.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, Python3 differentiates strings from bytes, whereas Python2 did not. So you need the variable `someData` to contain bytes rather than a string.
There are several solutions, but since you already use `struct.unpack()`, you can also use `struct.pack()` to create the data in the first place:

```python
e = bytearray()
```

and then:

```
e += pack('B', (ord(plaintext[i]) ^ ord(counter[i])))
```

Packing to format `B` (unsigned byte) converts a number from 0 to 255 into a byte. Remember to add `from struct import pack`, or similar.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion but it still produces and error, I don't want this post to turn into an open ended tutorial but this is what happened.  I added the line you provided above and I've checked it for accuracy.  On run the line is shown in the traceback followed by the error thus:
 e += pack('B', (ord(plaintext[i]) ^ ord(countert[i])))
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found.  
As my python expertise is limited I tried a few variants but to no avail.